# jQuery using $.grep filtering coming back false when it should be true

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

Hey all I have the following example array:

```
var arr = ['hello', 'something', 'trying', 'new', 'old'];
```

And the following is my filter code function:

```
function doSomething(sentOver) {
  console.log(sentOver);
  myNewArray = jQuery.grep(arr, function(n) {
    $('#output').text(n === sentOver);
  });
}
```

When I run the above using **doSomething('trying');** it comes back as *false* when the answer should be *true*.

What am I missing here to cause it to come back as *false*?

The JSFIDDLE can be found [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/5mj5ftvx/).

Comment: The last check with your grep is indeed false. So even though the value is "true" at some point, the last one is still false, which replaces ($('output').text(false)) the true with false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
$('#output').text(n === sentOver);
```

is executed for every item in the input array. The content of `#output` will be true for a "microsecond", but will get overwritten by last item `old`, which doesn't fullfill the condition.

The following code will display `true` for your input set.

```
var arr = ['hello', 'something', 'trying', 'new', 'old'];

function doSomething(sentOver) {
  console.log(sentOver);

  myNewArray = jQuery.grep(arr, function(n) {
    return n === sentOver;
  });

  $("#output").text(myNewArray.length > 0);
}

doSomething('trying');
```